# Route specification doesn't seem to match generated method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, view

When I refresh the page I get this error message:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"value", :controller=>"round"}):
  app/views/surveys/survey.html.erb:28:in `block in _app_views_surveys_survey_html_erb___3955880096442191391_70175035205180'
  app/views/surveys/survey.html.erb:22:in `_app_views_surveys_survey_html_erb___3955880096442191391_70175035205180'
  app/controllers/surveys_controller.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in survey'
  app/controllers/surveys_controller.rb:14:in `survey'    
  Rendered /Users/pitosalas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@repeatsurvey/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.5ms)
```

I am very confused by this. Why is the reference to program_participant_round_value_path causing that route to be missing?

Here's my routes file:

```
root to: 'programs#index'
  resources :programs do
    resources :participants do
      get 'survey' => 'surveys#survey'
    end
    resources :questions
    resources :rounds
    member do
      get 'report' => 'reports#report'
    end
  end
  resources :program do
    resources :participant do
      resources :round do
        put :value
      end
    end
  end
```

And here's the relevant rake routes line:

```
program_participant_round_value PUT    /program/:program_id/participant/:participant_id/round/:round_id/value(.:format) round#value
```

I have a controller action round#value.

Here's the relevant part of the view:

```
<%= content_tag :table do %>
  <%= content_tag :thead do %>
    <% 5.times do |q| %>
      <%= content_tag :th, "1" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <% form_tag program_participant_round_value_path do %>
    <%= content_tag :tbody do %>
      <%= render partial: 'surveys/value', collection: @values  %>
    <% end %>
    <%= submit_tag "Save" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `program_participant_round_value` route is expecting several parameters:

- `:program_id`
- `:participant_id`
- `:round_id`

You need to provide values for those parameters when you call the `program_participant_round_value_path` helper:

```
program_participant_round_value_path(program_id: @program, participant_id: @participant, round_id: @round)
```

Of course, variable names and such may be slightly different depending on how you are defining them in the controller.

Comment: And that affects the route that it looks for? Odd. Let me try. Thanks!

Comment: Ok progress, but now I get the error: No route matches {:action=>"value", :controller=>"round", :program=>1, :participant=>2, :round=>9} so I need to make some change to the routes. But before I go down that path, I would rather that the url for submitting the form look like ./program/1/participant/2/round/3/update. You seem to know this stuff cold. Could you give me a pointer? Thanks 10^6

Comment: Be sure to pass `method: :put` as an argument to `form_tag`.

Comment: Do you already have a `RoundsController#update`? If so, it'll look messy to get the `/update` at the end like that. Otherwise, you should be RESTful and keep the `/update` off and just `PUT` to `/program/1/participant/2/round/3`. That's the more conventional way of doing it. If you further want to explore this, I recommend starting a new question and linking to it in a comment here. I could help with that topic if you'd like. I'm addicted to getting Stack Overflow points. :)

Comment: Here's the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293929/updating-a-bunch-of-records-with-one-form